# How to fill in an Adobe document?

Tags: windows, open-source, pdf, pdf-viewer, pdf-editor

I am trying to apply for a scholarship for graduate school. I need to fill out the PDF file (it has fillable fields) and then send it in via email. It has to be completed electronically. When I open the PDF file, it opens in Adobe Acrobat. I am able to type in the boxes, but I am not able to do anything with the formatting (i.e., indent, bold, italicize, underline) unless I pay for the editing version. I think it is very unfair for the school to expect that we pay to subscribe to this version just to fill out the application. Maybe there's something I'm missing. Is there any way to change the formatting of the words in adobe acrobat without subscribing to the Pro version?

Thanks

Comment: Welcome to Software Recommendations! Please note that this site is about *recommending software meeting specific requirements,* not about *solving issues with software* you already have. If you intended to ask for software, please see  [What is required for a question to contain "enough information"?](//softwarerecs.meta.stackexchange.com/q/336/185) for a guide. Otherwise please check the `/help/ontopic` page of other SE sites to see where your question fits. You could start with [SuperUser](//superuser.com/help/on-topic), for example.

Answer (score 1):

If the school is using a form created by them to collect information, they are aware that the limitations of this form will result in un-formatted text. If the school staff is sufficiently qualified, the received forms can be auto-processed into a database, which would also strip off any formatting. This aspect of collecting this information also "levels the playing field" by keeping things uniform across the collected information, allowing a focus on the information, not the presentation.